# Quickly checking an inequality on a convex region

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-geometry

I previously posted this question to math.sx at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748015/quickly-checking-if-an-inequality-holds-on-a-convex-region but I'm thinking that MO may be more appropriate:
Let $C$ be a given convex polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing the origin and let $a$, $\mathbf{b}$, and $Q\succeq0$ be a given scalar, vector, and matrix respectively. Is there a fast way to verify if the expression $$a+\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}^TQ\mathbf{x} - \|\mathbf{x}\|\geq 0$$ holds for all $\mathbf{x}\in C$?  This function is not convex, but it seems that it ought to be simple enough to verify in some clever way.

One thought that I have had so far is as follows:  the gradient vector of the function $f(\mathbf{x})=\|\mathbf{x}\|$ is just $\mathbf{x}/\|\mathbf{x}\|$, which always has norm 1.  That means that any local minimizer of my function above must at least satisfy $$\|\mathbf{b} + 2Q\mathbf{x}\| = 1$$, which is described by an ellipse.  That at least narrows the search space somewhat.

Comment: How is your $C$ described? If it is given by linear inequalities, and they are not so many, you can write the KKT conditions.